# css background image not showing up

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out why this background image does not show up.  It seems like the image is getting sent to the browser, and that the css rule is getting applied.

When I inspect element I get these matched rules.  When I click on the 'images/o.png' link it shows me the expected image
    .player1_move {
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      background-image: url('images/o.png');
    }

----------- below is the css and html that I have ---------

```
  .player1_move {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-image: url('images/o.png');
  }

 <table>
  <tr>
    <td id = "0-0" class="player1_move"></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your cell is empty and that's why it's not showing.

Add this on your css:

```
table{
    empty-cells: show;
}
```